# More than one ResourceBundle for same locale

Tags: jsf, resourcebundle

I have two property files with same keys but different values. Now I'm trying to select which property file to use while the web application runs (like it work's with locales). Is this even possible in JSF?

Comment: What problem exactly are you facing when trying so? Or don't you already know how to load a single resource bundle in a JSF page?

Comment: I'm having a app that is for adults and childrens. Exactly the same app but different Strings. So I have langChildren_de.properties and langAdults_de.properties. Depending on the mode the user selects, the values should come out of the corresponding property file. Right now I'm using     <f:loadBundle basename="#{userSessionBean.kidsMode ? 'langChildren_de':'langAdults_de'}" var="langRes"/>. But I don't know if there is a more elegant way...

Comment: If you remove the `_de` part and externalize the static `lang` part, then that's indeed best what you can get.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.